Strimzi connect operator does not create plugins folder
I have deployed strimzi Kafka cluster in my local environment. I have also deployed strimzi connect in my local env too. I am want to run JDBC Source Connector to read data from Postgresql and write tit to a topic.
when I run my code, the JDBC connector jar file is not getting copied to /opt/kafka/plugins folder. When I log into connect pod and see that plugins folder is not created when connect cluster is deployed. If I create it manually and try copying the jar file, it requires a restart, when I restart every thing is reset.
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnect
metadata:
   name: my-connect-cluster
   namespace: strimzi
spec:
   replicas: 1
   bootstrapServers: my-kafka-cluster-kafka-bootstrap:9092
   config:
   group.id: "connect-cluster"
   offset.storage.topic: "connect-cluster-offsets"
   config.storage.topic: "connect-cluster-configs"
   status.storage.topic: "connect-cluster-status"
   plugin.path: "/opt/kafka/external-configuration/plugins"  # Kafka Connect plugin     path
   image: strimzi/kafka-connect:latest
template:
  pod:
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0  # Run as root to grant necessary permissions
externalConfiguration:
volumes:
  - name: plugins
    configMap:
      name: my-connector-plugins  # Use a ConfigMap to store the connectors



apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: postgres-source-connector
  namespace: strimzi
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: my-connect-cluster

spec:
  class: io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
  tasksMax: 1
  config:
    connector.class: io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
    tasks.max: "1"
    topic.prefix: "postgres-"  
    connection.url: "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/exampledb"  
    connection.user: "postgres"  # Username for PostgreSQL
    connection.password: "examplepassword"  # Password for PostgreSQL
    table.whitelist: "users"  
    mode: "bulk" 
    poll.interval.ms: "5000"  
    timestamp.column.name: "last_modified"  
    numeric.mapping: "best_fit" 
    value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter  
    value.converter.schemas.enable: "false" 


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: postgres
 labels:
   app: postgres
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
 matchLabels:
  app: postgres
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: postgres
   spec:
     containers:
    - name: postgres
      image: postgres:13
      env:
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: "examplepassword"  # Change this to a more secure password
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: "exampledb"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  selector:
  app: postgres
  ports:
   - protocol: TCP
     port: 5432
     targetPort: 5432


Strimzi does not allow you to configure the plugin.path and/or load plugins from ConfigMaps (which are anyway not suitable for plugins). The externalConfiguration field is - as the name suggests - designed for loading custom configurations.
If you want to add plugins to the Strimzi Connect cluster, please follow the docs: https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/deploying.html#using-kafka-connect-with-plug-ins-str
